# How do I use Youtube API to get the number of likes and dislikes of a video?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using Eclipse with Java and have downloaded the Google Api Java Client jar files and obtained the api auth. keys.

- How do I use it to get the amount of likes, view count and dislikes of a video?
- Is it possible to do so with country wise selection?

A sample code for example is well appreciated.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) really isn't hard to find, it even showcases how you can get the exact information you need (`"viewCount"`, `"viewCount"`, `"dislikeCount"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following Url of GoogleApi, you can get particular video view count and  likes, dislikes.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,statistics&id=%@&key=%@",videoId ,YOUTUBE_API_KEY];
```